# Why won't my event listener display modal on click?

Tags: javascript, html, function, element

I have an image and I would like the modal to be displayed when the image is clicked. The modal has a display of "none" initially.

Here is the (very simple)modal.

```
<div id="modal" style="background-color: #000;"> <!--MODAL---->
    <span id="close">&times;</span>
</div>

<img id="image" src="agave.jpg"/> <!--Click to display modal-->
```

This seems simple enough, why isn't it working?

```
var img = document.getElementById("image");

function displayModal(event){

   var modal = document.getElementById("modal");

   if(modal.style.display == "none"){

       modal.style.display = "block";
   }

   else{modal.style.display = "none";}
}

img.addEventListener("click", displayModal(event));
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be: (pass the function itself as the second argument)

```
img.addEventListener("click", displayModal);
```

This would pass the **result** of the function as second argument

```
img.addEventListener("click", displayModal(event),);
```